# How to configure multiple cassandra contact-points for lagom?

Tags: cassandra, lagom

In Lagom it appears the contact point get loaded from the service locator which accepts only a single URI.  How can we specify multiple cassandra contact-points?

```
lagom.services {
 cas_native = "tcp://10.0.0.120:9042"
}
```

I have tried setting just the contact points in the akka persistence config but that doesn't seem to override the service locator config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that I was missing was the session provider to override service lookup:

```
session-provider = akka.persistence.cassandra.ConfigSessionProvider
contact-points = ["10.0.0.120", "10.0.3.114", "10.0.4.168"]
```

was needed in the lagom cassandra config